# How do I populate dropdown list dynamically in Angular (Syncfusion Scheduler)

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, scheduler, syncfusion

I'm using the [Syncfusion Scheduler](https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-ui-components/angular-scheduler) in my Angular 8 application and I am customizing the view that pops up to create a new event. It comes with the `onPopupOpen()` function where you can add new elements. 
I want to add a dropdown list which displays all the clients of the current user (the `companyName` property). I load the data from the Mongo collection in the `ngOnInit()`:

```
  ngOnInit() {   

this.clientService.getClients().subscribe((data : any) => {
  this.clients = data.client;
})

  }
```

This is where I insert the dropdown element in the `onPopupOpen()` function:

```
  let dropDownList: DropDownList = new DropDownList({
        dataSource: [
        {text: this.clients[0].companyName, value: this.clients[0].companyName}

      ],
      fields: {text: 'text', value: 'value'},
      value: (<{ [key: string]: Object }>(args.data)).Client as string,
      floatLabelType: 'Always', placeholder: 'Client'
        });
```

How do I add this datasource line (`{text: this.clients[0].companyName, value: this.clients[0].companyName}` )  accordingly? So that it loops through `clients` response and it shows all the clients a particular logged in user has. Instead of the static [0]th position of the response.
Ive tried a for loop /  forEach, but that didnt work. Where should I put the loop in this scenario?

The `onPopupOpen()` function is called here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-agenda',
 // templateUrl: './agenda.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agenda.component.css'],
  providers: [DayService, WeekService, WorkWeekService, MonthService, 
AgendaService, MonthAgendaService, TimelineViewsService, 
TimelineMonthService],
  template: `<ejs-schedule width='100%' height='750px' locale='nl-AW' 
[eventSettings]="eventSettings"  (actionBegin)="onActionBegin($event)" 
[views]='views' (popupOpen)='onPopupOpen($event)'>  </ejs-schedule>`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the array `map` property.

Try:

```
ngOnInit() {   

  this.clientService.getClients().subscribe((data : any) => {
    this.clients = data.client;
    // once this.clients is populated, call `this.onPopupOpen();` to populate
    this.onPopupOpen();
  });

}
...

// take the clients array and create a new array of objects with text and value properties equal to the companyName of each element
dataSource: this.clients.map(client => ({text: client.companyName, value: client.companyName})),
....
```

Edit: I would have to see your full HTML and TypeScript to give you an optimal solution.

===========================================================
**After looking at their documentation (btw, they don't have the best documentation).**

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/schedule/data-binding/#binding-remote-data (Check out loading data via AJAX post)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-agenda',
 // templateUrl: './agenda.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agenda.component.css'],
  providers: [DayService, WeekService, WorkWeekService, MonthService, 
AgendaService, MonthAgendaService, TimelineViewsService, 
TimelineMonthService],
  template: `<ejs-schedule width='100%' height='750px' locale='nl-AW' 
[eventSettings]="eventSettings"  (actionBegin)="onActionBegin($event)" 
[views]='views' (popupOpen)='onPopupOpen($event)' (created)="onCreate()">  </ejs-schedule>`
})

....
@ViewChild('scheduleObj', { static: true })
    public scheduleObj: ScheduleComponent;
....
onCreate() {
 const scheduleObj = this.scheduleObj;
 this.clientService.getClients().subscribe((data : any) => {
  scheduleObj.eventSettings.dataSource = data.map((point, index) => ({
     id: index,
     Subject: point.companyName,
     StartTime: new Date(), // should come from your API,
     EndTime: new Date(), // should come from your API
   }));
 });
}
....
```

Comment: i tried this, and it gives me an empty dropdown , just a greyed out field :\

Comment: is it maybe because Clients isnt an array? It is an observable

Comment: But you populated in `ngOnInit` but you're concerned that both of them will run at the same time and `this.clients` will be `undefined` or `[]`? If that's the case, I will have a new solution for you.

Comment: I run console.log(this.clients) and it gives me undefined indeed.

Comment: When do you run `onPopUpOpen()`? I have made an edit, you can check it out.

Comment: I replaced the console.log(this.clients) and now it works, in the console I get an object with all the clients :)

Comment: but the dropdown remains empty

Comment: thank you for for effort, however,    this.onPopupOpen() does not work in ngOnInit. As they have a different way of operating. The onPopupOpen function is called in the <template> line

Comment: i dont understand what is going wrong. In my onPupUpOpen function,      console.log(this.clients) gives me an array of objects containing the clients. However, the dropdown list is still empty using `dataSource: this.clients.map(client => ({text: client.companyName, value: client.companyName})),`

Comment: I think you have to do it the way they want it, check out the `onCreate` method.

Comment: doesnt work man :( get all kinds of error messages as its messing with my current eventsettings things

Comment: the problem is in that loop when trying to add the clients to the dropdown i think

Answer (score 0):

We have validated your reported problem at our side by preparing the CRUD sample with MongoDB as a service. In that, we have using Dropdown Component as an additional (custom) field and the data source for the custom field is assigned from the Observable Data Services and it can be downloaded from the following link.

Code snippet:

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.selectedDate = new Date(2018, 1, 14); 
    this.eventSettings = { dataSource: this.dataManager }; 
    const clientObservable = this.clientService.getClient(); 
    clientObservable.subscribe((client: client[]) => { 
      this.dropDownDataSource = client; 
    }); 
  } 
  onPopupOpen(args: PopupOpenEventArgs): void { 
    if (args.type === 'Editor') { 
      // Create required custom elements in initial time 
      if (!args.element.querySelector('.custom-field-row')) { 
        let row: HTMLElement = createElement('div', { className: 'custom-field-row' }); 
        let formElement: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>args.element.querySelector('.e-schedule-form'); 
        formElement.firstChild.insertBefore(row, args.element.querySelector('.e-title-location-row')); 
        let container: HTMLElement = createElement('div', { className: 'custom-field-container' }); 
        let inputEle: HTMLInputElement = createElement('input', { 
          className: 'e-field', attrs: { name: 'EventType' } 
        }) as HTMLInputElement; 
        container.appendChild(inputEle); 
        row.appendChild(container); 
        let drowDownList: DropDownList = new DropDownList({ 
          dataSource: this.dropDownDataSource, 
          fields: { text: 'company', value: 'companyValue' }, 
          value: (args.data as { [key: string]: Object }).EventType as string, 
          floatLabelType: 'Always', placeholder: 'Event Type' 
        }); 
        drowDownList.appendTo(inputEle); 
        inputEle.setAttribute('name', 'EventType'); 
      } 
    } 
  }
```

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/269087/ze/sample1530536267